# How can I stop Overlay mousedown event from going to map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay, dom-events

After handling a mousedown event on the overlay (the ExtInfoWindow), I need to make sure the map click event handler doesn't execute, or in the map click event handler, I need to determine that the event is coming from an overlay click, and not handle it.  So, some way I need to not handle it twice.  What am I doing wrong below? It's for the ExtInfoWindow library, so I will not post the whole thing here. [Page with map is here](http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_gmap/exams/find.php?q%5Btext%5D=RALEIGH,%20NORTH%20CAROLINA,%20USA&q%5Bmode%5D=next&q%5Bhasloc%5D=Y&q%5Bsptext%5D=&q%5Bloc%5D=&q%5Bgb%5D=&q%5Bhasmoved%5D=Y&q%5Bhasdist%5D=&bounds%5Beast%5D=-79.020175910376&bounds%5Bnorth%5D=35.99995553167758&bounds%5Bwest%5D=-79.0754508737549&bounds%5Bsouth%5D=35.97203630485635&result_center%5Blat%5D=35.985997153167474&result_center%5Blon%5D=-79.04781339206545&&m%5Bsetvp%5D=Y&m%5Bvp%5D%5Blat%5D=35.98592397814075&m%5Bvp%5D%5Blon%5D=-79.04757499694824&m%5Bvp%5D%5Bzoom%5D=14&m%5Bsetwin%5D=Y&m%5Bwin%5D%5Bcent%5D=351&m%5Bwin%5D%5Bloc%5D=1114&m%5Bwin%5D%5Btab%5D=0).  Click on the info window.  Search for "console.log" in [extinfowindow.js](http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_gmap/system/themes/asp/js/extinfowindow.js) to see where the problem is.

```
  // Initialization:

  var stealEvents = ['mousedown', 'dblclick', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'onmousewheel'];
  for( i=0; i < stealEvents.length; i++ ){
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.container_, stealEvents[i], this.onClick_.bind(this));
  }



    if (map.ClickListener_ == null) {
      //listen for map click, close ExtInfoWindow if open
      map.ClickListener_ = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click',
        function(event) {
            if( map.getExtInfoWindow() != null ){
                    // problem: This executes even if the click is on the overlay!
                map.closeExtInfoWindow();
            }
            }
      );
    }


// overlay click event handler
ExtInfoWindow.prototype.onClick_ = function(e) {
   var evt = e ? e:window.event;

   evt.cancelBubble = true;
   evt.returnValue = false;

   if (evt.stopPropagation) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
   }

   if (evt.preventDefault) {
      evt.preventDefault();
   }

   evt.stop(); // from google.maps.MouseEvent

};
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use chrome dev tools, set breakpoints, look at the call stacks. The onClick function seems correct at first, however, it might be worth logging/checking the 'e' value, being considerate about the effects of the `bind` method. [must admit that I dont konw getting the event object crossbrowser] Other than this, we'd need a working application to help you out IMO.

Comment: @EricG On the overlay, I think it's just a usual DOM click type event, but then on the map, it's a google event with a lat and lon.

[The app is here.](http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_gmap/exams/find.php)
Search for console.log in extinfowindow.js

Comment: @EricG [Another link](http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_gmap/exams/find.php?q[text]=RALEIGH%2C+NORTH+CAROLINA%2C+USA&q[mode]=next&q[hasloc]=Y&q[sptext]=&q[loc]=&q[gb]=&q[hasmoved]=Y&q[hasdist]=&bounds[east]=-79.020175910376&bounds[north]=35.99995553167758&bounds[west]=-79.0754508737549&bounds[south]=35.97203630485635&result_center[lat]=35.985997153167474&result_center[lon]=-79.04781339206545&&m[setvp]=Y&m[vp][lat]=35.98592397814075&m[vp][lon]=-79.04757499694824&m[vp][zoom]=14&m[setwin]=Y&m[win][cent]=351&m[win][loc]=1114&m[win][tab]=0).  Click on the info window.

Comment: Please post an example where the code is readable. Your sample page is minified and unreadable.

Comment: @Marcelo I'm not sure what code you are referring to. [extinfowindow.js](http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_gmap/system/themes/asp/js/extinfowindow.js) where the problem is,  [exam_find.js](http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_gmap/system/themes/asp/js/exam_find.js), and the find.php code are all readable/not minified.

Answer (score 3):

Execute `MouseEvent.stop();` in the first handler. IE:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myOverlay, 'click', function(mouseEvent){
    mouseEvent.stop();
//Handle the click here
});
```

[See the Google Maps documentation for MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent)

Comment: Thanks.   I thought that would be it, but the map click event handler still gets called.

Comment: @dougd_in_nc, I haven't tested it but, if that's the case then it would be a bug. Do you have a page that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I just added a link in the question description.

Comment: @dougd_in_nc, Please post an example where the code is readable. Your sample page is minified and unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... The dom listener was listening for mousedown events not click events, therefore the click wasn't being cancelled.  I should have made it listen for click events.

```
var stealEvents = ['click', 'dblclick', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'onmousewheel'];
for( i=0; i < stealEvents.length; i++ ){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.container_, stealEvents[i], this.onClick_.bind(this));
}
```